# Why table::after element is created after the table > td element, not the table element?

Tags: css, pseudo-element, css-tables

I tried to add dot after a table, by using `table::after` selector to create a dot element and center it with `margin: 5px auto 5px auto;`. It works, but it seems dot is added after the first table column, not after the table itself:

[image]

Why and how to fix it?

Live code http://cssdeck.com/labs/ew6g4ntf/0

Comment: What makes you think that it's after the first column? When I inspect it with firebug, it seems to be outside the <tbody>

Comment: This rule `margin: 5px auto 5px auto;` should place it in the center of its container, and it looks like it's in the center of first table column. Yes in inspector it's behind table, but visually it looks like it's behind the first column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a somewhat weird way of doing it, but going along your solution, it's probably because that's how tables work best, on a cell basis. So that's why the table::after also resembles a cell.

But, if you put this whole thing in a div, and you float it to left, and you do this ::after thing with the div instead of the table, it will work well.

[Here's a preview](http://cssdeck.com/labs/xkpiu16b/0)

Comment: Yes, but HTML markup will be not clean, there will be additional `<div>` element there.

Comment: Yeah... I still think your best bet would be to add a <span class="dot"/> for a clear and easier to read mark-up, instead of the stuff::after.